# substituting printf with write for signal handling

Tags: c, linux

I just found out that printf isn't safe in signal handler. So I tried to use the write function to print to the console but it didn't work. For example, how would I use write() function to do something like this `printf("ID: %d Exit: %d", x, y);`
But I am confused on how to use format specifiers in the write function. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The write function doesn't support the use of format specifiers.  It just takes a pointer to a memory buffer of a given size and writes the bytes directly.

You can safely use the `sprintf` function to construct a string, then pass that string to `write`:

```
char str[100];
sprintf(str, "ID: %d Exit: %d", x, y);
write(1, str, strlen(str));
```

Comment: Is `sprintf` async-signal-safe? I may have scanned the lists too quickly, but I did not see it in the POSIX nor Linux tables. If not a async-signal-safe, it is probably not suitable for the OP’s present design.

Comment: @pilcrow The Linux `signal(7)` page lists functions that POSIX requires to be async-signal safe, but it doesn't mention anything regarding if other functions may be, and the individual man pages don't say one way or the other.  I did check the Solaris man pages which *do* say that `sprintf` and `strlen` are async-signal safe (and it would make sense that they would be, considering what they do).

Comment: Note: No need for `strlen(str)`.  The return value of `sprintf()` can be used to determine the length.

Comment: Solaris may implement `sprintf` safely. `glibc` does not, as it calls `malloc` from inside of `vsnprintf`. If you care of portability, don't do that.